# Eclipse 4 Text Control Values Not Refreshing

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, text, e4

I have an Eclipse 4 that I'm building with using a master(tree control)/detail(Part with Text controls) paradigm. A have a listener that captures node selection changes from the tree and passes the object to the detail Part via the `ESelectionService`.

I have print statements that verify the value changes of the text fields via the `setText()` and `getText()` methods.  Even though the `getText()`  methods records the new values, the new values are not actually being refreshed on the UI.  I have tried `.update()` and `.paint()` on the text controls to no avail.

Here's the (master) Part that has the `Tree` control:

```
package my.company.parts;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.Focus;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.MApplication;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EPartService;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.ESelectionService;
import org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ITreeContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.LabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MessageBox;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil;

import my.company.data.MyService;
import my.company.data.model.MyClass;

/**
 * 
 * 
 *
 */
public class MyBrowser {
    private Image myImage1;
    private Image myImage2;
    private TreeViewer treeViewer;
    @Inject
    private EPartService partService;
    @Inject
    private MyService myService;
    @Inject
    private ESelectionService selectionService;

    /**
     * Zero-argument constructor
     */
    public MyBrowser() {
    }


    @Inject
    @PostConstruct
    public void createControls(Composite parent, MApplication application) {
        try {

            if (!myService.validDbConnection())
                throw new SQLException();
            List<MyClass> stuff = myService.findAll();
            // Tree control icons
            createImages();

            GridData layoutData = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.TOP, true, true,
                    1, 1);
            parent.setLayoutData(layoutData);
            parent.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
            treeViewer = new TreeViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER);
            treeViewer.setContentProvider(new ViewContentProvider());
            treeViewer.setLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider());
            Object[] a = stuff.toArray();
            treeViewer.setInput(a);
            Tree tree = (Tree) treeViewer.getControl();
            tree.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                    TreeItem item = (TreeItem) e.item;
                    if (item.getItemCount() > 0) {
                        if (item.getData() instanceof MyClass) {
                            MyClass myClass = (MyClass) item.getData();
                            selectionService.setSelection(myClass);
                        }
                        treeViewer.refresh();
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            MessageBox messageDialog = new MessageBox(parent.getShell(),
                    SWT.ERROR);
            messageDialog.setText("Database Connection Error");
            messageDialog
                    .setMessage("Could not establish a connection to the database.  "
                            + "Ensure the correct database connection values have been set "
                            + "in the application preferences.");
            int returnCode = messageDialog.open();
            System.out.println(returnCode);
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createImages() {
        Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ViewLabelProvider.class);

        URL mpUrl = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("icons/list_16.png"),
                null);
        ImageDescriptor mpImageDcr = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(mpUrl);
        this.myImage1 = mpImageDcr.createImage();

        URL scenarioUrl = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("icons/et_16.png"),
                null);
        ImageDescriptor scenarioImageDcr = ImageDescriptor
                .createFromURL(scenarioUrl);
        this.myImage2 = scenarioImageDcr.createImage();
    }

    class ViewLabelProvider extends LabelProvider {

        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            if (element instanceof MyClass) {
                return ((MyClass) element).getName();
            } else
                return element.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public Image getImage(Object element) {
            if (element instanceof MyClass)
                return myImage1;
            else
                return myImage2;
        }
    }


    class ViewContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider {
        /**
         * 
         */
        public void inputChanged(Viewer v, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
        }

        /**
         * 
         */
        @Override
        public void dispose() {
        }

        /**
         * 
         */
        @Override
        public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
            return (Object[]) inputElement;
        }

        /**
         * 
         */
        @Override
        public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement) {
            if (parentElement instanceof MyClass) {
                Object[] children = { "Child" };
                return children;
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * 
         */
        @Override
        public Object getParent(Object element) {
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * 
         */
        @Override
        public boolean hasChildren(Object element) {
            if (element instanceof MyClass)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Cleanup
     */
    @PreDestroy
    public void dispose() {
        myImage1.dispose();
        myImage2.dispose();
    }

    /**
     * Sets control focus
     */
    @Focus
    public void setFocus() {
        // treeViewer.getControl().setFocus();
    }
}
```

Here's the (details) Part with the Text controls:

```
package my.company.parts;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.eclipse.core.databinding.DataBindingContext;
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans.BeanProperties;
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.IObservableValue;
import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Optional;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.Focus;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.IServiceConstants;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.ESelectionService;
import org.eclipse.jface.databinding.swt.WidgetProperties;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ComboViewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormAttachment;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;

import my.company.data.model.MyClass;

public class MyDetails {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    private Text txtId;
    private Text txtName;
    private Text txtDescription;
    private Label lblDescription;
    private Label lblId;
    private Label lblFaultResponseStrategy;
    @Inject
    private ESelectionService selectionService;

    public MyDetails() {
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the view part.
     *
     */
    @Inject
    @PostConstruct
    public void createControls(
            Composite parent,
            @Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SELECTION) @Optional MyClass) {

        System.out.println("@PostConstruct fired -- ");
        parent.setLayout(new FormLayout());

        lblId = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
        lblId.setAlignment(SWT.RIGHT);
        FormData fd_lblId = new FormData();
        fd_lblId.top = new FormAttachment(0, 8);
        fd_lblId.left = new FormAttachment(0, 5);
        lblId.setLayoutData(fd_lblId);
        lblId.setText("ID:");

        txtId = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);

        fd_lblId.right = new FormAttachment(txtId, -6);
        FormData fd_txtId = new FormData();
        fd_txtId.left = new FormAttachment(0, 136);
        fd_txtId.right = new FormAttachment(100, -16);
        fd_txtId.top = new FormAttachment(0, 5);
        txtId.setLayoutData(fd_txtId);

        txtId.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {

            @Override
            public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
                Text text = (Text) e.widget;
                System.out.println("From text modify event listener (id): "
                        + text.getText());
            }
        });

        Label lbl1 = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
        lbl1.setAlignment(SWT.RIGHT);
        FormData fd_lbl1 = new FormData();
        fd_lbl1e.right = new FormAttachment(lblId, 0, SWT.RIGHT);
        fd_lbl1.top = new FormAttachment(0, 34);
        fd_lbl1.left = new FormAttachment(0, 5);
        lbl1.setLayoutData(fd_lbl1);
        lbl1.setText("Name:");

        txtName = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        FormData fd_txtName = new FormData();
        fd_txtName.left = new FormAttachment(lbl1, 6);
        fd_txtName.right = new FormAttachment(100, -16);
        fd_txtName.top = new FormAttachment(txtId, 5);
        txtName.setLayoutData(fd_txtName);

        txtName.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
            @Override
            public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
                Text text = (Text) e.widget;
                System.out.println("From text modify event listener (name): "
                        + text.getText());
            }
        });

        lblDescription = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
        lblDescription.setAlignment(SWT.RIGHT);
        lblDescription.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Segoe UI", 9,
                SWT.ITALIC));
        FormData fd_lblDescription = new FormData();
        fd_lblDescription.right = new FormAttachment(lblId, 0, SWT.RIGHT);
        fd_lblDescription.top = new FormAttachment(0, 57);
        fd_lblDescription.left = new FormAttachment(0, 5);
        lblDescription.setLayoutData(fd_lblDescription);
        lblDescription.setText("Description:");

        txtDescription = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.MULTI);
        FormData fd_txtDescription = new FormData();
        fd_txtDescription.top = new FormAttachment(txtName, 5);
        fd_txtDescription.left = new FormAttachment(lblDescription, 6);
        fd_txtDescription.right = new FormAttachment(100, -16);
        txtDescription.setLayoutData(fd_txtDescription);

        txtDescription.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {

            @Override
            public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
                Text text = (Text) e.widget;
                System.out
                        .println("From text modify event listener (description): "
                                + text.getText());
            }
        });



        refresh(myClass);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void dispose() {
    }

    /**
     *
     */

    @Focus
    public void setFocus(
            @Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SELECTION) @Optional MyClass myClass) {

        System.out.println("@Focus fired -- ");
        refresh(myClass);

    }

    public void refresh(MyClass myClass) {
        if (myClass!= null) {
            txtId.setText("{0}");
            txtName.setText("{DEFAULT NAME}");
            txtDescription.setText("{DEFAULT DESC}");

            System.out.println("MyClass is NOT null");

            System.out.println("{B}Char Count (name): "
                    + txtName.getCharCount());

            id = String.valueOf(myClass.getId());
            name = myClass.getName();
            desc = myClass.getDescription();
            System.out.println("{" + id + "}{" + name + "}{" + desc + "}");
            txtId.setText(id);
            txtName.setText(name);
            txtDescription.setText(desc);
            System.out
                    .println("getText(): {" + txtId.getText() + "}{"
                            + txtName.getText() + "}{"
                            + txtDescription.getText() + "}");
            System.out.println("{A}Char Count (name): "
                    + txtName.getCharCount());

        } else {
            txtId.setText("{-1}");
            txtName.setText("{NO NAME}");
            txtDescription.setText("{NO DESC}");
            System.out.println("MyClass is null");
        }

        if (myClass!= null) {

            // create new Context
            DataBindingContext ctx = new DataBindingContext();

            // define the IObservables
            IObservableValue target = WidgetProperties.text(SWT.Modify)
                    .observe(txtName);
            IObservableValue model = BeanProperties.value(myClass.class,
                    "name").observe(myClass);

            // connect them
            ctx.bindValue(target, model);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we need to see some code.

Comment: I'm not sure it is part of your problem, but I think should not combine PostConstruct and Inject. Or do you want to create your UI everytime the selection changes? You should probably only use PostConstruct on createControls() and Inject on refresh() directly.

Comment: Thank you @christoph.keimel!  That was exactly the problem.  Removing the @Inject annotation on the createControls() method did the trick!